# Who brings a program from Secondary memory(Hard Disk) to Primary Memory(RAM) for execution?

Tags: memory, memory-management, operating-system

In the book "Operating System Concept by SILBERSCHATZ, GALVIN & GAGNE", they've mentioned that,

> Main Memory(Primary memory) and the registers built into the processor itself are the only storage that CPU can access directly

This statement has caused a lot of confusion. If CPU can not access Secondary Memory, then how does it fetch a program from Secondary Memory?

Comment: It is usually fetched into RAM _indirectly_. These mostly, though not necessarily, brought in by DMA accessing the memory bus in parallel with the CPU. Of course in addition to memory the CPU typically also has direct access to non-storage I/O registers and storage ROMs of some sort from which to bootstrap the system.

Comment: @doynax But, DMA is only meant for the access from primary memory(RAM) and not from secondary memory. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_memory_access

Comment: The DMA controller fetches read data from the disk controller and stows it into CPU-addressable RAM, operating autonomously once started. The details differ but in the simple case the disk controller simply exposes a source I/O register space somewhere on the bus for extracting buffered data, from which an independent DMA controller may be programmed to read and deposit the results to RAM. Think of it as the disk controller keeping a small internal RAM buffer for the most recently read sector which it reads directly into, and which it exposes to the bus the CPU/DMA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CPU can't access Secondary memory directly doesn't mean It can't access it anyway. when System is booted, BIOS inbuilt program (in ROM) copy boot loader (from secondary bootable device) to RAM's memory and ask cpu to continue execution from that particular address.
Once CPU starts executing Boot loader, Boot loader calls necessary function to read from disk (secondary storage) and copy your OS kernel image into memory. transfer of data is done through I/O ports.
You have your kernel image into memory, and thus boot loader ask cpu to jump to kernel's entry point. You have your kernel starting up this point.
Kernel setup OS environment, load up necessary drivers (including disk/cd-rom driver). After this point, It is up to OS disk driver that It performs I/O port operation or DMA access to load up data from secondary storage.
Generally DMA is preferred because It does not involve CPU for polling up data from device, but It is little difficult to code.
I hope I cleared your doubt :)